# app.use(express.static()) at the end of the program

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As far as I understand when I use `app.use(middleware)` this middleware will be called on every request on a server.

So when I use `express.static()` as a middleware it will to be called on every request too but in this case it's not needed to be called on any request so why do I need to put it at the top of my program? I haven't seen anybody puts it before `app.listen()`. Why is this so?

Does it cause any performance degradation?

Comment: Middlewares are applied in the order they are used. It makes sense to serve files that physically exist, so static middleware goes first, otherwise requests could be processed  by other middlewares instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have in mind the [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) works as a pipe, so, all middleware will be executed in the same order you add them.

E.G.

If you have installed the express `JSON` middleware, the `static` middleware and an `authorization` middleware (in this order), and your endpoint the flow of a request will be:

```
               /                    Server                           \
Client -----> |  json -> static -> authorization -> endpoint -> EGEH  |
               \                                                     /
```

> Note: EGEH stands for `Express Global Error Handler`.

But if some of those elements send a response or throw an error (caught by the `EGEH`) the flow must be different.

In general, if you know your statics would be the last option, you could use it at the end (after the `server.listen` or whatever), and that would not affect the behavior, however, if that is the case may be a better option is to use the server engine (Nginx, Apache, etc) to dispatch those files to the customer instead of make node spend CPU to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next
So that's why express static usually go first

[image: middleware next middleware]